# Navigating through SQL rows in JAVA

Tags: java, sql, sql-navigator

I'm trying to navigate through rows after a select statement was made.
Currently, i'm using this: 
for the -> (next) button:

```
if(dataset_all.isLast());
                dataset_all.first();
            dataset_all.next();
```

and for the <- (prev) button:

```
if(dataset_all.isFirst());
                dataset_all.last();
            dataset_all.previous();
```

somehow, it's not working. It says that it reached the end of the column when it didnt.

Is it right? Or the problem is elsewhere?

Forgot to mention that the "dataset_all" variable is the ResultSet.
thanks in advance

Comment: ResultSet must be created in your case with this flag: TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE: The result can be scrolled; its cursor can move both forward and backward relative to the current position, and it can move to an absolute position. Show us the code you used to create the dataset_all variable

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I worked it out.
I did this:

for the -> (next) button:

```
if(!dataset_all.next())
    dataset_all.first();
```

And for the <- (previous) button:

```
if(!dataset_all.previous())
        dataset_all.last();
```

it worked all right! Shouldnt it?